# Find spiral 2D matrix (List of Lists) of ints in a clockwise spiral

Tags: python, python-2.x, comparative-review, interview-questions

I got this question during my interview with Microsoft.

The question called 2D Snake. I'm wondering if my solution 1 passes the test, but if my solution 1 different from solution 2.

> Let's have some fun with 2D Matrices! Write a method `find_spiral` to
>   traverse a 2D matrix (List of Lists) of ints in a clockwise spiral
>   order and append the elements to an output List of Integers.
>
> Example:
>
> Input Matrix:
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 3]
> [4, 5, 6]
> [7, 8, 9]
> ```
>
> Output List: [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]

## Solution 1

```py
def find_spiral(matrix):

    output = []

    while matrix:
        row = matrix.pop(0)
        output.extend(row)
        matrix = zip(*matrix)[::-1] 

    return output
```

## Solution 2

```py
def find_spiral(matrix):    
    spiral_list = []
    if matrix == None or len(matrix) == 0:
        return list
    m = len(matrix) 
    n = len(matrix[0])
    x=0
    y=0

    while(m>0 and n>0):
        if(m==1):
            i = 0
            while i < n:
                spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
                i += 1
                y += 1
            break
        elif(n==1):
            i = 0
            while i < m:
                spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
                i += 1
                x += 1
            break

        i = 0
        while i < n-1:
            spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
            i+=1
            y+=1

        j = 0
        while j < m-1:
            spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
            j+=1
            x+=1

        i = 0
        while i < n-1:
            spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
            i+=1
            y-=1

        j = 0
        while j < m-1:
            spiral_list.append(matrix[x][y])
            j+=1
            x-=1

        x+=1
        y+=1
        m=m-2
        n=n-2

    return spiral_list
```

Test cases:

```
Input   
[[1,2],[3,4]]
Expected Result
[1, 2, 4, 3]
Input
[[1,2],[3,4]
Expected Result
[1, 2, 4, 3]

Input
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
Expected Result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 11, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7]

input
[[1,2],[3,4]
Expected Result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

Input
[[1,0],[0,1]]
Expected Result
[1, 0, 1, 0]

Input
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Expected Result
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

Comment: First code taken from https://github.com/tmantock/python/blob/master/snake.py,

Answer (score 5):

Just reviewing solution 1.

1. The solution is clever (repeatedly extract the first row and rotate the remainder by a quarter-turn) and the code terse.
2. However, the code destructively modifies the input `matrix` by popping the first row. This would be surprising to the caller and might make it more difficult to use or to test.
3. The code does not work in Python 3: it fails with the exception:

   ```
   TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable
   ```

   In Python 3 you would have to write `list(zip(...))`. Since Python 2.7 is [close to its end of life](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) it is a good idea to write code that would be easy to port to Python 3. In this case you could use

   ```
   from future_builtins import zip
   ```

   to get a version of the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function that's compatible with Python 3.
4. If the input is an \$n×n\$ matrix, then rotating the remainder takes \$O(n^2)\$ and this has to be done \$O(n)\$ times, leading to a total runtime of \$O(n^3)\$. But intuitively it ought to be possible to output the spiral in \$O(n^2)\$.

   We can achieve this by implementing the same approach (repeatedly extract the first row and rotate the remainder by a quarter-turn) but instead of modifying the *matrix*, we instead modify our *system of coordinates*. This is probably easiest to see if I give the code first:

   ```
   def find_spiral_2(matrix):
       "Return list of elements of matrix in clockwise spiral order."
       h, w = len(matrix), len(matrix[0]) # Height and width of remainder
       i, j = 0, -1                # Current position in spiral
       di, dj = 0, 1               # Current direction of movement
       spiral = []
       while h > 0:
           # Output top row
           for _ in range(w):
               i += di
               j += dj
               spiral.append(matrix[i][j])
           # Remove top row and rotate quarter-turn
           h, w = w, h - 1
           di, dj = dj, -di
       return spiral
   ```

   The way this works is that we maintain the state of the algorithm in the form of the height \$h\$ and width \$w\$ of the remainder of the matrix, the coordinates \$(i, j)\$ of our current position along the spiral, and a vector \$(di, dj)\$ giving the current direction of movement along the spiral path.

   To output the top row, we follow the current direction for \$w\$ steps, leaving us in the top-right corner of (the remainder of) the matrix. Then, as in your solution, we remove the top row and rotate the remainder though a quarter-turn—or rather, we modify our coordinates to have this effect. Removing the top row subtracts 1 from \$h\$. Rotating the remainder through a quarter-turn causes \$w\$ and \$h\$ to swap (height becomes width and vice versa) and the current direction of movement to rotate through a quarter-turn. You should check that the line `di, dj = dj, -di` achieves this.

   It should be clear that this does not modify `matrix`, and runs in \$O(n^2)\$ as required.